# How do I upgrade the Ruby version of my project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, rvm, version

I recently started learning Rails using Ruby 1.9.3p385, and I'm trying to develop a small project with it.

I'm using Linux so I installed Ruby using RVM.

I developed a few pages, following some tutorials. I would like to upgrade my project to use Ruby 2.0.0. What do I have to do?

I installed Ruby 2.0.0 with RVM:

```
rvm install 2.0.0
```

Everything seems OK, so I tried to use it:

```
rvm use 2.0.0-p247
```

But when I try to run my Rails server using `rails server`, I get the following message:

```
bash: rails : command not found
```

I've read the [RVM documentation about upgrading Ruby](http://rvm.io/rubies/upgrading) but I don't really understand what it does; I'm afraid of breaking everything.

Does it will upgrade my project in a way it will use Ruby 2.0.0 or what should I do?

Next, I will want to upgrade also to Rails v4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your gemset which comes with new Ruby version is empty. Try this:

```
gem install bundler # this will install bundler
bundle # this will use bundler to install required gems
rails server
```

Comment: It seems all good, server is running. I had "bundle is complete", then some green lines, which mean good to me, and then this : Depending on your version of ruby, you may need to install ruby rdoc/ri data:

<= 1.8.6 : unsupported
 = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
 = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
>= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay! is it good ? then, what "upgrading ruby" on rvm documentation means ?  thanks a lot

Comment: @Tomane Yes, it's normal output when you install rails. Those steps in "upgrading ruby" cover copying gemset from one ruby version to another, migrating gemsets etc.

Answer (score 2):

Did you run `rvm use 2.0.0-p247` or did you use `rvm use 2.0.0-p247 --default`? The later will set Ruby v.2.0 as the default for your system. Failure to do that will revert your Ruby to whatever RVM's default is the next time you log into your system or open a new terminal window.

When RVM installs a new version of Ruby, it installs only the default gems. It CAN [upgrade a Ruby to another version, and optionally install the existing gems](http://rvm.io/rubies/upgrading) as it does so, but that's not what you asked it to do: `rvm install 2.0.0` only installs Ruby. At that point you have to install the other gems you need, which would include Rails.

My general practice when installing various versions of Ruby and the gems I like is to use two command-line pipes to dump my existing gems, then (re)install them. First I switch to an existing Ruby whose gems I want to duplicate, then run:

```
gem list | cut -f1 -d' ' > ~/gem_list
```

Then I switch to the newly installed one, and run this:

```
xargs gem install < ~/gem_list
```

This does a completely clean install of the gems, outside of RVM's commands.

Why? Habit. Paranoia based on some "experiences" I had in the past with RVM.

Once that's all done and I have brand-spanking-new Ruby and gems, I'll proceed with running bundler or other housekeeping chores.

Comment: I used the first one, (without --default) and noticed then that I had to do 'use version' with every new shell. Thanks for the tips and explanations

Answer (score 1):

when you install a new ruby version, you have to reinstall all the gems for that version.  start of by installing bundler first.  Then run bundle in your rails root directory.  When you encounter no errors, you're good to start the rails server. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

run `bundle install` on the application root, you need to reinstall all your dependencies for the new version of Ruby.